# sciptprocessor increasing CPU usage in Angular 10 with changes to input stream. Also how to destroy it

Tags: angular, webrtc, cpu-usage, scriptprocessor, ngondestroy

Looking to free up CPU resources from a volume meter I have implemented on a device-access component route.  This volume-meter component takes an existing stream set up in a parent component (device-access), using a WebRTC `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` call.  The parent component permits the user to switch audio input devices and have the volume meter reflect the input's volume/gain/feedback reflected in the volume meter.

There is currently an issue where on multiple switches of devices, the CPU level gradually goes upwards.  Additionally, this device-access page is a gateway to a video meeting component. A common scenario will have the user going back to this deice-access page.  When the user goes back , the onaudioprocess is still running and compounds the CPU usage.

Following is the code.  I have implemented an ngOnDestroy in the child component (volume-meter), but it does not seem to be impacting the process still running.  When i switch the input audio device (in the subscribe), I want to kill the scriptprocessor and restart it.  How do I do this?

```js
export class VolumeMeterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  private stream: MediaStream = null;
  private audioContext: AudioContext = null;
  private meter: any = null;
  private canvasContext: any = null;
  // height and width of the volume meter
  private WIDTH: number = 146;
  private HEIGHT: number = 9;
  private rafID: number = null;
  private mediaStreamSource: any = null;
  private clipping: boolean = null;
  private lastClip: number = null;
  private volume:number = null;
  // averaging: how "smoothed" you would like the meter to be over time.  
  // Should be between 0 and less than 1.
  private averaging: number = .95;
  // the level (0 to 1) that you would consider "clipping"
  private clipLevel: number = .98;
  // clipLag: how long you would like the "clipping" indicator to show after clipping has occurred, in milliseconds.
  private clipLag: number = 750;
  private loopInstance: any = null;
  private processHandle: any = null;
  // @ts-ignore
  @ViewChild('meterElement', {read: ElementRef, static: false}) meterElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // nothing here for now
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.streamService.stream$.subscribe(stream =>{
      this.stream = stream;
      if (this.loopInstance) {
        this.processHandle.stop();
        this.cleanupMeterOnChange();
      }
      this.initializeMeter();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.cleanupMeterOnChange();
  }

  cleanupMeterOnChange():void {
    // cleanup the canvasContext and meter onDestroy
    // best practice is to cleanup the the canvasContext as it has processes
    this.meter = null;
    this.canvasContext = null;
    this.drawLoop = null;
  }

  initializeMeter():void {
    this.canvasContext = this.meterElement.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    // update audioContext to whatever is available from browser
    try {
      (window as any).AudioContext = (window as any).AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
      this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
      this.mediaStreamSource = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream);
      // Create a new volume meter and connect it.
      this.meter = this.createAudioMeter(this.audioContext);
      this.mediaStreamSource.connect(this.meter);
      this.loopInstance = this.drawLoop();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log('Error setting up the volume meter. ' + error);
    }
  }

  drawLoop = () => {
    // clear the background
    this.canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
    // check if we're currently clipping
    if (this.meter.checkClipping()) {
      this.canvasContext.fillStyle = 'red';
    } else {
      this.canvasContext.fillStyle = 'green';
    }
    // draw a bar based on the current volume
    this.canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, this.meter.volume * this.WIDTH * 1.4, this.HEIGHT);

    // set up the next visual callback
    this.rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( this.drawLoop );
  }

  createAudioMeter = audioContext => {
    const processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    processor.onaudioprocess = this.volumeAudioProcess;
    this.processHandle = processor;
    processor.clipping = false;
    processor.lastClip = 0;
    processor.volume = 0;
    processor.clipLevel = this.clipLevel;
    processor.averaging = this.averaging;
    processor.clipLag = this.clipLag;

    // this will have no effect, since we don't copy the input to the output,
    // but works around a current Chrome bug.
    processor.connect(audioContext.destination);
    processor.checkClipping =
      checkClipping;

    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    function checkClipping() {
      const that = this;
      if (!that.clipping) {
        return false;
      }

      if ((that.lastClip + that.clipLag) < window.performance.now()) {
        that.clipping = false;
      }
      return that.clipping;
    }

    processor.shutdown =
      function(): void {
        this.disconnect();
        this.onaudioprocess = null;
      };

    return processor;
  }

  volumeAudioProcess( event ): void {
    this.clipping = false;
    const buf = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    const bufLength = buf.length;
    let sum = 0;
    let x;

    // Do a root-mean-square on the samples: sum up the squares...
    for (let i = 0; i < bufLength; i++) {
      x = buf[i];
      if (Math.abs(x) >= this.clipLevel) {
        this.clipping = true;
        this.lastClip = window.performance.now();
      }
      sum += x * x;
    }

    // ... then take the square root of the sum.
    const rms =  Math.sqrt(sum / bufLength);

    // Now smooth this out with the averaging factor applied
    // to the previous sample - take the max here because we
    // want "fast attack, slow release."
    this.volume = Math.max(rms, this.volume * this.averaging);
  }
}
```

The components markup:

```
<canvas id="meterElement" #meterElement width="146" height="8"></canvas>
<p class="level-label">Microphone volume level</p>
```

I have tried subscribing to the canvas using a ViewChild and unsubscribing, but have not had much luck.  Anyone have any insight into a strategy to run this more efficiently. Would subscribing to drawLoop (and extracting it to a service), be the best answer?

I know WebRTC recommends audioWorklets:
https://alvestrand.github.io/audio-worklet/

- this is a draft and does not have Safari adoption.  It does seem to be a better solution long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `close()` on an AudioContext to stop all its nodes and to make it release any system resources that it needs to use to do its thing. I think adding this to your `cleanupMeterOnChange()` method should improve the performance.

```
cleanupMeterOnChange():void {
    // ...
    this.audioContext.close();
}
```

Comment: ended up with this:

`this.audioContext.close().then(function() {})`

Just had to have the method return the promise. Its a slight improvement in CPU usage, but, until webaudio worklets are adopted by Safari, this is what I am going to have to use.